# Stuck on level 7 "if (practice) {" section

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm stuck on the following section of level 7:

```
if (practice) {
  perfect;
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I believe I have all of the keys that I should have, but I can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you'll need `%`.

That said, here's a hint: you won't need to use `%` on the parentheses, only the curly braces.

If that's not helping, comment with your best sequence so far and we'll go from there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you collected the `g` from the house near the beginning of the level, you can get to the start of the content to be deleted with two moves remaining and then use `dG` to delete until the end of the text.

As clozach mentioned above, you can alternatively get the `%` from the nearby hut and use `d%` to delete until the end of the else block.